# How to call/execute another ASP.net page from the parent ASP.Net page without disrupting the flow of events?

Tags: asp.net

When a button/link is clicked, I want this URL to be called followed by the execution of the following statements.

The ASP.Net page is in C# btw.

```
Function A
   statement A
   call abc.apsx
   statement B
```

abc.aspx is a silent page, doesn't display anything on the page but creates an output.txt file. So when abc.aspx is called, output.txt file is created and Statement B is executed seamlessly. Hope I made sense.

I have no .Net programming knowledge. Please help me.

Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a HttpWebRequest object to call abc.apsx page

e.g.

```
HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://host/abc.apsx");
```

or Using WebClient to fire a request to the web page.

```
   WebClient client = new WebClient ();

        // Add a user agent header in case the 
        // requested URI contains a query.
        // important to add user-agent to emulate a real request from browser. 
        client.Headers.Add ("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");

        Stream data = client.OpenRead ("http://host/abc.apsx");
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (data);
        string s = reader.ReadToEnd ();
        Console.WriteLine (s);
        data.Close ();
        reader.Close ();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Tried this, it doesn't work for some reason, not sure why. I even tried Server.Execute() but it is giving me "Error executing child request"... Any pointers?

Comment: try using WebClient to fire a real request to that page.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what [HttpServerUtility.Execute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.execute.aspx) is for.

Comment: Permissions.  You mention an error in a comment above... ?  "Error executing child request".  Well, this is not the *real* error.  Catch the exception and look at the InnerExection.Message value to see the real error.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you having the abc.aspx act as a standalone page?

From how your question reads, you're goal is to get the Output.Txt file, thus, why not have a class that builds that output.txt file as a separate object which your initial page can call?

And then, if you need it accessible to the user, have abc.aspx call this class as well.

Or you can go with codemeit's suggestion of the httpwebreques (which if abc.aspx is on a separate domain this is probably your best course of action)

Comment: I am not well versed with .Net at all. I am into PHP. This is a quick fix (temporary) thing. The easiest way for now until we migrate the whole thing to PHP. Moreover I wrote the abc.aspx file in VB and the project is in C#. I know it is a mess but the original programmer's implementation is way to tricky for me to understand and make changes in a short time.